# how to know location of return address on stack c/c++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, x86, stack

i have been reading about a function that can overwrite its return address.

```
void foo(const char* input)
{
    char buf[10];

    //What? No extra arguments supplied to printf?
    //It's a cheap trick to view the stack 8-)
    //We'll see this trick again when we look at format strings.
    printf("My stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n% p\n\n"); //%p ie expect pointers

    //Pass the user input straight to secure code public enemy #1.
    strcpy(buf, input);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    printf("Now the stack looks like:\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n%p\n\n");
}
```

It was sugggested that this is how the stack would look like

Address of foo = **00401000**

**My stack looks like:**
00000000
00000000
7FFDF000
0012FF80
**0040108A <--  We want to overwrite the return address for foo.**
00410EDE

**Question:**
-. Why did the author arbitrarily choose the second last value as the return address of foo()?

-. Are values added to the stack from the bottom or from the top?

- apart from the function return address, what are the other values i apparently see on the stack? ie why isn't it filled with zeros

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the CPU (family) that you are using, and also on the ABI. You should probably tag your question appropriately so that it's clear what you're talking about here (I'm guessing x86 on Linux or Windows ?).

Comment: It also depends on the compiler. Newer versions of Visual Studio and GCC reorder the stack to make such attacks harder. If `buf` is located _after_ the return address, you'd need a buffer _underflow_ to overwrite the return address. And underflows are a lot rarer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one above it is the previous EBP (`0012FF80`). The value above the prev-EBP is always the return address.

(This obviously assumes a non-FPO binary and 32bit Windows)<sup>1</sup>.

If you recall, the prologue looks like:

```
push ebp      ; back up the previous ebp on the stack
mov ebp, esp  ; set up the new frame pointer
```

and when a function is called, e.g.

```
call 0x00401000
```

The current EIP is pushed on the stack (used as the return address), so the stack after the prologue looks like:

```
[ebp+0xc]  ; contains parameter 1, etc
[ebp+0x8]  ; contains parameter 0
[ebp+0x4]  ; contains return address
[ebp]      ; contains prev-EBP
```

So for each `%p`, printf uses the next 4 bytes starting from `[ebp+0xc]` (the first `%p` parameter). Eventually you hit the previous EBP value stored on the stack, which is (`0012FF80`) and then the next one is the Return Address.

Note these addresses must 'make sense', which they clearly do here (though it may not be 'clear' for all).

Re Q2) The stack grows down. So when you `push eax`, 4 is subtracted from `esp`, then the value of eax is moved to [esp], equivalently in code:

```
push eax
;  <=>
sub esp, 4
mov [esp], eax
```

---

1. The book is *Writing Secure Code*, yes?